# RegSetValueEx does not set in unicode project build

Tags: c++, unicode, registry

I'm trying to write data to registry, but it always writes foreigner language instead because the setvalue is "MyApp"

```
CStringA temp(setvalue);//setvalue is CString type
const BYTE* pData = (const BYTE*)(LPCSTR)temp;
lResult = RegSetValueEx(hKey, path, NULL, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)pData, sizeof(pData));
RegCloseKey(hKey);

if(lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS || lResult == ERROR_MORE_DATA)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

thanks.

Comment: Why don't you convert from ANSI to UTF16?

Comment: What's more, why are you still using ANSI at all on Windows. Much better to do everything with wide strings.

Comment: I wish you can explain some more because above code I'm trying to convert the data to the same type that is acceptable by the function, RegSetValueEx().

Comment: Do you understand about different text encodings? Your code puts ANSI encoded text into a buffer expecting UTF16 encoded text. It's a pain in the neck converting encodings all the time. Better just to use UTF16 all the time

Comment: I have basic knowledge about text encoding, but not much.  The variable setvalue is const char * that is passed from the interface and I can not change it.  So I have to convert to UTF16 whenever necessary but when I call RegSetValueEx(), I didn't know that it expects unicode because it just puts const BYTE* type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you are converting CString to BYTE* is causing the problem. No need of using CStringA.

Try this conversion of CString to TCHAR. This should work

```
LPTSTR lpszData = new TCHAR[setvalue.GetLength()+1]; // setvalue is CString type...
_tcscpy(lpszData , csTemp);

lResult = RegSetValueEx(hKey, path, NULL, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)lpszData, setvalue.GetLength()+1);

delete[] lpszData;// don't forget to do this.
```

Comment: thanks for the code snippet.  I use the code and it works after making the change to the last parameter from setvalue.GetLength()+1 to ((setvalue.GetLength()+1) * sizeof(TCHAR)) otherwise it will not write the last two characters.

Comment: That is because the last parameter of `RegSetValueEx()` expects the number of bytes, not the number of `TCHAR`s, that are in the `lpData` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Try RegSetValueExA(). You are calling a function which is expecting unicode strings.  the A() function takes ANSI args

Comment: May I know which parameter in the RegSetValueEx() that is unicode because I'm still learning how to differentiate them.

Comment: Both the `lpValueName` and `lpData` parameters.  `lpValueName` is very easy to determine because it is declared as an `LPCTSTR`, which is a "pointer to a const TSTR", and `TSTR` is a pointer to a `TCHAR`, where `TCHAR` is Ansi/Unicode depending on the presence of the `UNICODE` conditional. As for the `lpData` parameter, that is declared as a `const BYTE*`, so it is not readily apparently from just the declaration that it actually requires `TCHAR` data as input. You have to decyher that from the documentation. When assigning to a REG_SZ registry value, `lpData` requires `TCHAR*` input.

Answer (score 0):

Any Win32 API function that accepts `TCHAR`, `LPTSTR` or `LPCTSTR` parameters will accept either Ansi or Unicode data depending on whether the `UNICODE` conditional is defined during compiling (RTL functions like `_tcscpy` use the `_UNICODE` conditional instead). So what's really happening in this case is that when you call `RegSetValueEx()` in your code, it gets resolved by the compiler to either calling `RegSetValueExA()` (Ansi) or `RegSetValueExW()` (Unicode) depending on the `UNICODE` conditional.

The `CStringA` class is for Ansi data only. You have to convert its data to Unicode when calling `RegSetValueExW()`.

To do what you are attempting, you need to either:

1) call `RegSetValueExA()` explicitally instead of `RegSetValueEx()` generically if you contiinue using the `CStringA` class:

```
CStringA temp(setvalue);
lResult = RegSetValueExA(hKey, path, NULL, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)(LPSTR)temp, (temp.GetLength() + 1) * sizeof(CHAR));
```

2) Use the `CString` class instead of the `CStringA` class.  `CString` is based on `TCHAR`, so it is also influenced by the `UNICODE` conditional, and thus matches the format that `RegSetValuEx()` is expecting:

```
CString temp(setvalue);
lResult = RegSetValueEx(hKey, path, NULL, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)(LPTSTR)temp, (temp.GetLength() + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR));
```

In the latter case, if your `setvalue` variable is already a `CString`, then just use it as-is, no need to create a `temp` copy of it:

```
lResult = RegSetValueEx(hKey, path, NULL, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)(LPTSTR)setvalue, (setvalue.GetLength() + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR));
```